# Debugging inefficient Project Euler 58

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve Project Euler's Problem 58.

For some reason, when I run the following code, it makes it through around 3000 rings before my computer freezes, presumably from how taxing the code is. I'd get the solution given enough resources, but at present, I'm taking too long.

However, it's as efficient as I can get it. I don't know what I could improve to solve the problem.

The function `isPrime` simply takes an Int and returns if it's prime.

The problem and my current solutions are below.

```
{-|
 - Problem 58
 -
 - Starting with 1 and spiralling anticlockwise in the following way, a square 
 - spiral with side length 7 is formed.
 -
 - 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
 - 38 17 16 15 14 13 30
 - 39 18  5  4  3 12 29
 - 40 19  6  1  2 11 28
 - 41 20  7  8  9 10 27
 - 42 21 22 23 24 25 26
 - 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 -
 - It is interesting to note that the odd squares lie along the bottom right 
 - diagonal, but what is more interesting is that 8 out of the 13 numbers    lying
 - along both diagonals are prime; that is, a ratio of 8/13 ≈ 62%.
 -
 - If one complete new layer is wrapped around the spiral above, a square spiral
 - with side length 9 will be formed. If this process is continued, what is the
 - side length of the square spiral for which the ratio of primes along both 
 - diagonals first falls below 10%?
 -}

import Data.List (genericLength)
import Data.List.Split (splitPlaces)
import EulerFunctions (isPrime)

-- Each ring is another concentric circle in the spiral. 
-- The first 3 are [1], [2..9], and [10..25]
type Ring = [Int]

-- Returns an infinite list of rings.
rings :: [Ring]
rings  = [1] : splitPlaces [8,16..] [2..]

-- Given a ring, returns the numbers on its corners.
corners     :: Ring -> [Int]
corners [1]  = [1]
corners ring = let end  = last ring
                   diff = (length ring) `div` 4
                in map (\n -> end - n * diff) [0..3]

diagPrimes      = scanl1 (+) $ map (genericLength . filter isPrime . corners) rings
diagLengths     = [1,5..]
diagPrimeRatios = zipWith (/) diagPrimes diagLengths

p58 = fst . head . filter ((< 0.1) . snd) $ [1,3..] `zip` tail diagPrimeRatios
```

Comment: Perhaps explain first the (essence) of what PE#58 is...

Comment: It's in the comments! :D

Comment: I haven't done any profiling or testing, so this is just guesses, but: in `corners`, `length ring` gets increasingly costly, and more importantly even if `length` were constant-time, `corners` itself would get increasingly costly. Perhaps you can use some arithmetic to replace `map corners rings` with a directly-computed list containing just corners without spending so much time skipping non-corners. I would also say that `isPrime` is easily a suspect for optimization.

Comment: I recommend representing your ring as `[[A]]` for some type `A`, so that each list in the list represents a "row" which always starts with a corner and ends right before another corner. Then the `corner` function is constant time. You can generate this "ring" from a flat list `[a]` in linear time (even if that list is infinite, for any `a` at all!). Then, the choice of concrete type is important - instead of just `Int` for the value, store a `(Int, Bool)` where the bool represents primality - then you can be sure you compute `isPrime` exactly once per natural, when you create the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Compilation

As always on Stack Overflow, I feel I need to make sure people are 1. compiling their code instead of using ghci 2. using optimizations.  Think of Haskell more like C in that you should compile to binary and use `-O2`, and not like Python where you just assume interpreted is a-ok.  So in short:

```
ghc -O2 -fllvm so.hs
```

If you do this you'll see your algorithm does terminate in a moderate amount of time - a couple minutes and low heap use.

## Algorithm Issues

Why the heck does it take a couple of minutes?  Lets look!

1. `corners` is building a list of ints then taking the corners.  Why?  You know the length of the side at each new wrapping, just get the four numbers!  `[1]`  then `[3,5,7,9]`, `[13,17,21,25]`. That is, add 2,2,2,2.. 4,4,4,4... 6,6,6,6...  `replicate 4 (sidelength-1)` each time.
2. [deleted] I thought you were re-verifying primes.
3. A minor point and hidden by your lack of type signatures, but your diagLengths arithmetic is all doubles - use integer arithmetic then cast for oh so meaningless difference in performance  `diagLength = map fromIntegral ([1,5..] :: [Int])`.

EDIT: So I thought the main issue was primes which I was wrong on.  At any rate, the idiomatic solutions I've tried yield results in ~0.3 seconds so it is doable.  I think building and traversing these largish lists for `corners` is rather killer as that costs allocation and memory accesses.

Comment: Thank you! :) If you're interested, here is the final solution I arrived at! https://github.com/danmaheshwari/Project-Euler/blob/master/EulerAnswers/p58.hs

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly take a brute force approach, there is a very simple functional solution.

Firstly, remark that you only ever need to consider the corners of the spiral. And you can generate those numbers directly (without ever counting the numbers in between). There is a very simple geometric sequence for the corners in the given 7-length spiral:

```
[3,5,7,9],[13,17,21,25],[31,37,43,49]
```

Note the differences between consecutive elements in each list are constant, and the constant difference per list is increasing according to `[2,4,6..]`, and the difference between the last corner of one side and the first of the next side is twice the difference between consecutive values of the first list. This prose corresponds exactly to the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

corners :: [[Integer]]
corners = [1] : go 3 2 where 
  go i0 !d = let l = i0+3*d 
                 d' = d+2 
             in [i0,i0+d,i0+2*d,l] : go (l+d') d'
```

Note that the first corner is a special case. Also note the use of bang patterns - it is important for functions like these to be strict (corners never examines `d` so it must be forced manually). This is an important performance consideration.

Next, consider a function which computes the ratio of primes in a single list. Since it must consider the old ratio, it should also take the old ratio as a parameter:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes.Testing (isPrime)

primeRatio :: (Int, Int) -> [Integer] -> (Int, Int) 
primeRatio pR nums = foldl' (\(!p,!t) n -> (p + fromEnum (isPrime n), 1+t)) pR nums
```

The `fromEnum` converts `False` to `0` and `True` to `1` directly (instead of an `if`) - otherwise this function is straightforward. Note, again, the bang patterns and the use of `foldl'` - both important for performance here. Also, the primality test is the highly efficient [Baille PSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) implemented by  the excellent arithmoi package - what primality test you use will significantly effect your performance.

Now we can finally write a fast loop which consumes each corner list in linear time:

```
  go !rIndex (cs:css) tgt pR  
    | tgt pR'   = 2*rIndex+1
    | otherwise = go (rIndex+1) css tgt pR' 
      where pR' = primeRatio pR cs
```

Note that the final answer (the number of rows) is computed directly from the index (the distance from center to outer row). This must always be an odd number, which is the case for the expression `2*x+1`. The check for termination is just encoded as a parameter to this function - we don't have to decide what it is yet. If the termination check fails, then all we do is update the current ratio with the next element in the corners list! How simple.

We have one final consideration: the ratio is below 10% for the first few rows. So we must treat those specially:

```
euler58 :: Integer
euler58 =  
  let prefix = 4 -- Number of cases to handle specially

      -- Special and non special cases
      (first,rest) = splitAt prefix corners 

      -- Initial part where the ratio is allowed to fall below the targe
      initVals = foldl' primeRatio (0,0) first 

      go !rIndex (cs:css) tgt pR  
        | tgt pR'   = 2*rIndex+1
        | otherwise = go (rIndex+1) css tgt pR' 
          where pR' = primeRatio pR cs 

  in go prefix rest (\(nPrimes, nTotal) -> (nPrimes%nTotal) < (1%10)) initVals
```

This computes the answer (26241) in less than half a second on my machine even when compiled without optimizations. I didn't even bother trying to optimize further - perhaps it could be pushed to be much faster, but it is already "instant" so there doesn't seem to be a point.